# Insert items in DynamoDB using lambdas without losing data

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS and I am trying to load data into a DynamoDB using lambda functions and python. The problem I have is the following: When I try to load a record into a table, the items that have the same Partition Key as the element I'm trying to insert are removed from the table. This is the code that I'm using (I got it from the AWS documentation):

```
import boto3
from pprint import pprint


def put_car(car_id, car_type, message, dynamodb=None):
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='eu-west-1')

    table = dynamodb.Table('Cars')
    response = table.put_item(
       Item={
            'car_type': car_type,
            'car_id': car_id,
            'message': message,
            }
    )
    return response

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    car_resp = put_car("1", "Cartype1",
                           "Car 1")
    print("Put car succeeded:")
    pprint(car_resp)
```

A possible solution would be to read all the records first and load them all again, including the record I wanted to insert, but this solution seems quite inefficient and I think there may be some easier way to do it.

Comment: How is the primary key in your dynamodb table constructed? Does it have both hash and sort keys?

Comment: The primary key is composed by the partittion key (car_type, which can take 4 possible values) and the sort key (car_id, which is a unique value for each car)

Comment: So your problem is you try to insert a new item, where the value for the partition key "car_type" exists already, but the value for the sort key "car_id" does not yet exists, and it inserts the new record, but all the existing records with the same parition key "car_type" get deleted?

Comment: That's it, all records that have the same car_type (the partition key) as the item I'm trying to insert are deleted.

Comment: that's very strange. can you recreate it by creating entries in dynamodb through aws console manually?

Comment: Yes, I finally decided to re-create the table on my own, because it was previously created by a partner and apparently it was badly created, because now it works fine. So thanks for your help.